# cannot prove function in frama-C

Tags: c, frama-c, loop-invariant, why3

I am having a problem regarding the function proving in frama C. my code used for proving looks like this :

```
#include <limits.h>
/*@ 
    requires len>=0 && \valid(arr + (0 .. len-1));
    ensures 0<= \result < len;
    ensures \forall integer j; 0 <= j < len ==> arr[j] < \result;
    assigns \nothing;
*/

int find_min(int* arr, int len)
{
   int min;
   min=arr[0];
    /*@ 
        loop invariant \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> arr[j] < min;
        loop invariant 0 <= min < i <= len;
        loop assigns min , i;
        loop variant len -i;
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void main (void)
{
    int a[] = {3, 5, 18, 12, 12};
    int r = find_min(a, 5);
    //@ assert r == 3;
}
```

This is a program that tries to look for smallest array value. The result of the program will be used to prove if the variable fulfills the conditions that is used in frama-C.

I am currently stuck at this invariance here :

[image]

I have done various methods before reaching this conclusion, including changing the "ensures..", but whenever I do that the proved goals will reduce from 13/14 to 12/14, therefore I am currently unsure what to change to increase the prove goals to 14/14. I really need help regarding this because I am really new to frama C. Any response regarding this problem is really appreciated.

Comment: OT: What is the purpose of `k`? As far as I can see it's assigned but never used.

Comment: I don't know frama, but your condition `0 <= min < i` doesn't make sense. The variable `min` holds the actual data in the array and should have no relationship to the indices. Separately, `i <= len` seems wrong unless frama is supposed to consider the final value of `i`. Did you mean to use `k` here? You don't use it _anywhere_, and I've been wondering why it exists at all. But `0 <= k < i <= len` would make sense for that variable despite its pointlessness.

Comment: @Support Ukraine yeah you are right...I have erased that code already but seems like it does not change the problem, but thanks for the response and the pointer anyways

Comment: @paddy the `i<=len` is correct: a loop invariant is supposed to hold at the end of each complete (i.e. not ended by a `break` ) loop step, including the last one.

Comment: @paddy yep I have changed the code by erasing the k variable here..I didn't notice that before..but regardless of that change, if I changed the loop invariant in question, it would result in reduction of prove goals so I thought the problems lied elsewhere.. perhaps you could notice if there are another problems on the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed several issues in your specification. First, the main `ensures` clause is at odds with what you describe:

> tries to look smallest array value

implies that you want something like `\result < arr[j]`. Moreover, since this is supposed to be the smallest, there should be an index for which the equality holds, i.e. you should use `<=` rather than `<`. All in all, we should have

```
ensures small_value: \forall integer j; 0 <= j < len ==> \result <= arr[j]
```

(NB: it's always a good thing to give a name (here `small_value`) to your clauses, it makes it easier to identify them in the logs)

Moreover, you're returning the smallest value, not the index thereof, hence your first `ensures` clause is incorrect.

Finally for the contract, there's a small issue in the `requires` clause as well, which will only become apparent if you use  `-wp-rte` to ensure that there are no runtime errors in addition to verifying the contract itself: since you always look at `arr[0]`, you cannot have an empty array, i.e. you must have `len > 0`.

Now, let's have a look at the invariant: the first invariant must be updated to reflect the change in the `ensures`. As mentioned in comments, the second one should only speak about the interval of `i`, there's no reason for `min` to be within those bounds. And `i` can be `0` (in fact, it is `0` when entering the loop).

With all this, you can prove that `f` fulfills its contract. However, this is not sufficient to prove the assert in `main`. Namely, `small_value` only ensures that you return a *smaller* value, but not *the smallest*. For that we need another ensures, namely

```
ensures min_value: \exists integer i; 0<= i < len && \result == arr[i];
```

and of course the corresponding invariant

```
loop invariant min_so_far: \exists integer j; 0<= j < i && min == arr[j] || min == arr[0];
```

(Note that `min_so_far` needs a special case to take into account the fact that we start the loop with `min == arr[0]`)

To sum up, with the following file

```c
#include <limits.h>
/*@ 
    requires valid_arr: len>0 && \valid(arr + (0 .. len-1));
    ensures small_value: \forall integer j; 0 <= j < len ==> \result <= arr[j];
    ensures min_value: \exists integer i; 0<= i < len && \result == arr[i];
    assigns \nothing;
*/

int find_min(int* arr, int len)
{
   int min;
   min=arr[0];
    /*@ 
        loop invariant small_so_far: \forall integer j; 0 <= j < i ==> min<=arr[j];
        loop invariant min_so_far: \exists integer j; 0<= j < i && min == arr[j] || min == arr[0];
        loop invariant loop_index: 0 <= i <= len;
        loop assigns min , i;
        loop variant len -i;
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

void main (void)
{
    int a[] = {3, 5, 18, 12, 12};
    int r = find_min(a, 5);
    //@ assert r == 3;
}
```

and Frama-C 28.0 + Why3 1.6.0 + Alt-Ergo 2.5.2
`frama-c -wp -wp-rte example.c` proves all the verification conditions.

Comment: damn you are very good at this....thank you so much!! I was frustrated over this for days!!!